# Adding a new directory to a GitHub repository branch and merging back to the trunk

Tags: merge, github

I'm having trouble merging a branch back to the trunk after adding a new directory.

I created a new branch BUG_BRANCH, made a few code changes, added a directory, and added several files to that directory.  I used "git add ." to add my changes for committing to my local branch. Then "git commit -am 'message here'". I then pushed my branch up to GitHub "git push origin BUG_BRANCH", checked out the main development branch again "git checkout dev", and grabbed any changes that had happened since I'd created my branch "git pull origin dev".

My problem occurred when I tried to merge the changes from my BUG_BRANCH to dev "git merge BUG_BRANCH". For each file within the newly created directory, I got "error: cannot stat 'path': Permission denied". When I log into GitHub, I see my changes hanging out in the remote copy of my branch. But I can't merge them into dev, and I can't even seem to get back to BUG_BRANCH locally; I get the same error message.

Looking around on StackOverflow, it seems that I could have added the directory using the -A option of add if I could get back to my branch. But I can't. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned in "[git rebase: `error: cannot stat 'file': Permission denied`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970879/git-rebase-error-cannot-stat-file-permission-denied)", this should be an error seen mainly on Windows.
It is usually related to files locked by a Windows process, either an anti-Virus or an IDE (Visual Studio, Eclipse, ...).
Make sure no other processes are running when trying to make your checkout or merge, and see if the issue persists.

> TortoiseGIT process that blocks those files. Open task manager and end process `TGitCache.exe`.

The [OP virtuesplea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/175754/virtuesplea) reports:

> Killing the TGitCache.exe process (from the [other topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970879/git-rebase-error-cannot-stat-file-permission-denied/7112088#7112088)) ended up being the solution

Comment: Killing the TGitCache.exe process (from the other topic) ended up being the solution. Thanks!

Comment: @virtuesplea: excellent. I have included your solution in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: It did not solved the problem to me. :/ Still looking for an answer.

Comment: Visual Studio was locking the file. Just closed it and the checkout worked. Thanks!

Comment: i had to reboot to get the file released. as soon as it came back up, my merge went through.

Answer (score 4):

The main problem here is that the editor/IDE is locking the file/folders. When you close the editor/ide, the file/folder will disappear and you can change branches/merge/rebase.

Different branches might contain different folders, so when branches are changed/merged/rebased, the editor/ide reloads the file system.

Maybe you did not allow the editor/ide to perform this reload or some settings are there which does not allow this. I encountered a similar problem in visual studio.

To solve this, just close the editor/ide.