# git error: cannot stat <filename> : Protocol error

Tags: git, bitbucket, pull

I can't pull/push to remote repo in bitbucket or change branch locally.  I am getting the following errors.

```
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Performing inexact rename detection: 100% (651/651), done.
error: cannot stat 'public/location-chambre-meublee/pictures?body_icons.png': Protocol error
error: cannot stat 'public/location-chambre-meublee/pictures?chambre-meublee-montreal.jpg': Protocol error
error: cannot stat 'public/location-chambre-meublee/pictures?colocation-montreal-canada-irie-location.jpg': Protocol error
error: cannot stat 'public/location-chambre-meublee/pictures?colocation-montreal-etudiant-irie-location.jpg': Protocol error
error: cannot stat 'public/location-chambre-meublee/pictures?colocation-montreal-irie-location.jpg': Protocol error
error: cannot stat 'public/location-chambre-meublee/pictures?home-banner.jpg': Protocol error
error: cannot stat 'public/location-chambre-meublee/pictures?icons-1.png': Protocol error
error: cannot stat 'public/location-chambre-meublee/pictures?icons-2.png': Protocol error
error: cannot stat 'public/location-chambre-meublee/pictures?icons-3.png': Protocol error
error: cannot stat 'public/location-chambre-meublee/pictures?logo.png': Protocol error
error: cannot stat 'public/location-chambre-meublee/pictures?merci-banner.jpg': Protocol error
error: cannot stat 'public/location-chambre-meublee/pictures?proto.jpg': Protocol error
error: cannot stat 'public/location-chambre-meublee/pictures?recherche-colocation-montreal-irie-location.jpg': Protocol error
error: cannot stat 'public/location-chambre-meublee/pictures?trouver-une-colocation-a-montreal-irie-location.jpg': Protocol error
```

How can I resolve this or remove these files in bitbucket?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this can help, even if your problem doesn't have to do with git rebase:

[git rebase error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970879/git-rebase-error-cannot-stat-file-permission-denied)

Basically it is saying that you have to close any programs using those files (sometimes using the task manager).

If this doesn't work, I would recommend cloning the project in a different location and then copying all the files you modified to that new location under the correct path. Then, you can commit and push from there without any problems.