# Returning back to master causes an error

Tags: git

Here is my git log:

```
59fb0ca <- 3546ed8 <- 653d53s(HEAD, master)
```

and I want to go back 59fb0ca commit to check out what I did so I do:

```
git checkout 59fb0ca
59fb0ca(HEAD) <- 3546ed8 <- 653d53s(master)
```

Now the HEAD points where I need to go over. After I play with the commit with no modification or adding files, I want to go back to the tip of the branch which is 653d53s. So I do

```
 git checkout master
```

But git complains with below message:

> git checkout master
>
> error: cannot stat 't2.txt' : permission denied.

I do not know why I do not have the permission on the file.

Comment: Could you give us a bit of context. Is t2.txt part of your repo? What are it's permissions? Does it exist?

Comment: Yes, the t2.txt was commit at 653d53s.

Comment: Have you tried running `git checkout master` multiple times and continued to get this error?

Comment: Is `t2.txt` open in another process (say a text editor or something like that)?

Comment: Actually I did `git checkout -f master` and it shows another error: **unable to create file t2.txt (Permission denied)**.

Comment: I think this is a windows specific problem where another process has control over that file so git is unable to stat or create it.

Comment: As you guessed, I am working on Windows with Git Bash.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87329/discussion-between-hwasoo-lee-and-skyler).

Comment: Did you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970879/git-rebase-error-cannot-stat-file-permission-denied

Answer (score 1):

When you are switching between the branches, `git` will restore or remove files based on the commits.

This is windows issue where the `t2.txt` is locked up by one of the windows application or server.

Try closing down all the application which you think might be culprit (in my case it was Visual studio) and retry

`git checkout master` or `git reset --hard origin/master`

which will reset to master `HEAD`