# can't change my php project to develop branch with git in windows when merge

Tags: php, git

Hello all I am intermediate in git and want to merge develop into master branch.

When i checkout to master it was good but, when merge with my develop branch i get this error with the following command :

```
git merge develop 


**error: cannot stat 'empresas/presupuesto/acciones': Permission denied**
```

And then force the checkout with -f command

```
git checkout -f develop 

the response was :

**fatal: cannot create directory at 'empresas/presupuesto/acciones': Permission de nied**
```

can't change to develop now. any kind help?

```
UPDATE LASTEST LOG:

    Usuario1@MiPC MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/scmsistema (master)
$git rebase --continue
No rebase in progress?

Usuario1@MiPC MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/scmsistema (master)
$ git rebase --abort
No rebase in progress?
```

Comment: when i made rebase the response is 
`No rebase in progress?`

Comment: i made the possible duplicate with no success.

Comment: The link I mentioned suggests closing every process accessing the repo, plz read whole post and let me know if we need more solution.

Comment: @hessamhedieh dear contributor. not solved need to delete master and clone develop into a fresh master

Comment: Im glad u find the solution, but as this question is duplicate of link, (as u found answer there) there is little value to add answer here, maybe u should consider deleting the post if u want

Comment: @hessamhedieh hey i go to many conflicts now in master to solve can you help me to delete master and clone develop to a fresh branch master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First part of question is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970879/git-rebase-error-cannot-stat-file-permission-denied)

for re creating `master` simply do this on `develop` branch

```
git branch -d master
git checkout -b master
```

if you have uncommited work in master and dont mind losing them use

```
git checkout -- .
```

for more info on above command see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17227791/5552166)

Comment: can you explicite the -- . for education pourposes.

Comment: when i try to change to master from develop it is was many code conflicts (like 500+)  , but in develop i have the fresh code then with hessam say delete master and checkout -b like a charm! thanks!.

Comment: Your branch is up to date with 'origin/develop'.

Comment: @ElvisTechnologies, You are welcomed, Edited my answer for a link to `git checkout -- .`.