# How to solve Permission denied errors after git checkout branch?

Tags: git, git-branch

I am learning git from scratch and following some tutorial and I got this error:

```
 Yasser@pc MINGW64 ~/Documents/repos/Branching (Development)
 $ git checkout master
 Switched to branch 'master'
 Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
   (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

 Yasser@pc MINGW64 ~/Documents/repos/Branching
 $ git st
 fatal: failed to stat 'C:/Users/toshiba/Documents/repos/Branching': Permission denied

 Yasser@pc MINGW64 ~/Documents/repos/Branching
 $ git branch
 fatal: failed to stat 'C:/Users/toshiba/Documents/repos/Branching': Permission denied
```

Why I get this error Permission denied errors after git checkout branch?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970879/git-rebase-error-cannot-stat-file-permission-denied